# Imagem (BITMAP) para String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc, controller

Nunca trabalhei com nada parecido e gostaria de inserir uma imagem numa base de dados e pelo que vi a melhor maneira é transformar uma imagem para string, ja procurei e encontrei algumas maneiras mas fiquei bloqueado. E a única maneira que tenho de armazenar imagens é numa pasta fora da base de dados, mas depois como pretendo fazer uma galeria nao tem como filtrar as imagens atraves do CarType.

[image: Inserir imagem (View)]

[image: Controller]

[image: Model]

[image: Insert]

```
public ActionResult Insert(Cars cars, HttpPostedFileBase photo)
    {
        string directory = @"~\Images";


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            int recordsCreated = CreateCar(
                         cars.Brand,
                         cars.Model,
                         cars.CarType,
                         cars.PlateDate,
                         cars.Image);
        }
        if (photo != null && photo.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);
            photo.SaveAs(Path.Combine(directory, fileName));
            return RedirectToAction("../Rent/Gallery");
        }
        return View();


    }
```

Comment: Fala amigo, beleza? Seja bem vindo ao SOPT! Quando for fazer alguma pergunta aqui no site, dê preferência a postar seu código ao invés de disponibilizar as imagens. Assim podemos te ajudar de forma mais eficiente e sua pergunta será avaliada de forma mais positiva. Refatore sua pergunta colocando seus códigos e deixe apenas as imagens das telas se realmente for relevante para a pergunta, ok? Abraço!

Comment: Use um [`MemoryStream`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netframework-4.7.2) para criar um `byte[]` a partir da imagem e então salve esse `byte[]` no banco de dados como um blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar converter para uma string do tipo Base64, neste caso tente isto :

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(Path))
{
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
        byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();

        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        return base64String;
    }
}
```